# Add new row to SELECT results

Tags: t-sql

Say I have a table with the column '*CreatedDate*'. I am interested in creating an SQL statement that can get me a list of all years except add *one* more year at the end of the result.

**TSQL:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(CreatedDate) as FY from MyTable ORDER BY FY ASC
```

Current results returned by above query:

> 2016
>
> 2017

I would like the final results to be:

> 2016
>
> 2017
>
> 2018

I do not want to accomplish this by using a TemporaryTable or a View. I do not want to create new tables and truncate them. Is there anything I can do to the *select* statement to get me what I need?

Comment: You can use a stored procedure instead: Build the cursor in there and return that.

Comment: Use a union with a DATEADD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
from (
      SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(CreatedDate) as FY 
      from MyTable
      union
      SELECT max(YEAR(CreatedDate))+1 as FY 
      from MyTable
     )x
ORDER BY FY ASC
```